# PMF of cos$^2(x)$ of a uniform distribution X

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm trying to simulate a probability function in the shape of $\cos^2(\theta)$ of a measured natural phenomena where particles are measured about the origin (0,0) of 2 axes (x,y) plane. At the origin we record most particles (i.e., the probability to find a particle in a single point is the highest at (0,0)).

To simulate the function, I use a software that produces 1 number of $10^6$ numbers uniformly in the range of $\left[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$ for each axis (this way, $\cos^2$ reaches max value at (0,0)), while there is no dependency between the axes.

Thus I calculate (for a single axis, X and Y are random variables here):

$$X\in \left\{-\frac{\pi}{2},-\frac{\pi}{2}+10^{-6},...,\frac{\pi}{2}-10^{-6},\frac{\pi}{2}\right\}
\\\implies p_X(x_i)=P(X=x_i)=\frac{1}{10^6}
\\Y=\cos^2(X)\implies Y\in\left\{0,...,1\right\}
\\\implies p_Y(y_i)=P(Y=y_i)=P(\cos^2(X)=y_i)=P(\cos(X)=\pm\sqrt{y_i})=P(X=\arccos(\pm\sqrt{y_i}))
\\\implies p_Y(y_i)=P(X=\arccos(\sqrt{y_i}))+P(X=\arccos(-\sqrt{y_i}))=P(X=\arccos(\sqrt{y_i}))+P(X=\pi-\arccos(y_i))
\\\implies p_Y(y_i)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{10^6}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{10^6}=\frac{1}{10^6}$$

This is where I get stuck. How can I create a random variable, based on X, with a normalized PMF $\propto \cos^2$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To create a random sample with density proportional to $\cos^2(x)$, I would probably use [rejection sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling)

Comment: @Henry "M here is a constant, finite bound on the likelihood ratio f(x)/g(x)" (from the link). How do you proceed when f(x) is independent of x (i.e, the pdf of unif(a,b)=$\frac{1}{(b-a)}$) and g(x) is dependent on x (i.e, the pdf of cos^2(x) is $\frac{1}{\pi\cdot\sqrt{x-x^2}}$? Thus M is dependent of x: $M=\frac{1}{\pi \cdot (b-a)\cdot\sqrt{x-x^2}}$